# Magento admin error code 503

Tags: magento, admin

I have just tried installing a Magento extension but something went wrong and I deleted all the files.

Now when trying to login to magento admin I get the error: Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 503

Thought I might have deleted too many files but checked with the backup files and they are identical.

Any ideas where to look? Error code does not say much

Comment: Have no maintenance_flag file. Frontend works fine - only admin is not accessable

Comment: delete files is not enough, and it's not the right method to uninstall a module. This module have made some changes on database? check the setup files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your main Magento directory for a file `maintenance.flag` and delete it if it's there.  It sounds like your store went into maintenance mode to install the extension, and since something went wrong it was never turned off maintenance mode.

Comment: have no files named like that

Comment: Have you emptied Magento's `/var/cache` folder?  Might also try removing the `core_resource` database entries for the extension that failed to install, although if you restored from a database backup those shouldn't even be there.

Comment: Tried emptying the /var/cache folder - and that helped!!! You are a life saver - Thanks